# error after closing project or browser without logout and try to login again in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have this error Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. after close the project before logout and login before time expire please assist here is my session controller
 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' =>120,

'expire_on_close' =>true,
```

Comment: Do you click the remember me checkbox when you login?

Comment: yes but even if i dont click it still direct me to homepage and give me error Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: **Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.** is stock 404 error,  to answer this question you need to provide more detail.

Comment: I want to get laravel default login if user close project or browser but now go to the home page and that error Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found

Comment: Please show you controller. Do you have auth middleware setup inside your controller? Please show the routes and controller. Also, which guard are you using? Default user guard or custom guard. Lastly try clearing route cache, and redo the login expire step on incognito mode.